# Append an array values into select option Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Im currently using Laravel

here's my jquery code so far :

```
$('button[type="search"]').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('car.plate_no') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}',
            'driver_id' : $('select[name="driver_id"]').val(),
            'fine_date' : $('input[name="fine_date"]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data.status == true) { 
            var result = ''; 

            $.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) {  
            result += '<div>'+ data.plate_no +'</div>'; 
            }); 
            $('#search-result').html(result); 
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {

        } 
    });  
});
```

and here's my form code so far :

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group filter-btn">
     <button class='btn btn-info' type='search'>Search</button>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="search-result"></select>
```

everything works fine, data is being returned.

how do i append plate_no data into select box and store it to database .

any idea ?

Comment: Where is select box ?

Comment: Neither the objective or your specific problem are clear. We have no idea what is or isn't working in code shown or what the data looks like

Comment: sorry, updated thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:
inside foreach:

```
result += '<option value='+data.plate_no+'>'+data.plate_no+'</option>';
$('#search-result').html(result);
```

html:

```
<select name="" id="search-result">
</select>
```